# CS50P Problem Set 4 (Little Professor): timed out while waiting for program to exit

Tags: python, cs50

I am working on this problem. The code works fine when I try. I can input the level, check my answers, and the program prints out the required responses. But check50 returns this message while doing the unit tests,

> 'timed out while waiting for program to exit'

There should be a silly mistake which I am missing. This is the code I have written.

```
import random

def main():
    num_repeat = 10
    score = 0
    level = get_level()

    while num_repeat > 0:
        x = generate_integer(level)
        y = generate_integer(level)
        guess_remain = 3
        try:
            while guess_remain > 0:
                answer = int(input(f'{x} + {y} = '))
                if answer == x + y:
                    score += 1
                    break
                else:
                    print('EEE')
                    guess_remain -= 1
                    if guess_remain == 0:
                        print(f'{x} + {y} = {x+y}')
                    continue

        except ValueError:
            print('EEE')
            pass
        else:
            num_repeat -= 1

    print(f'Score: {score}')
    return 0


def get_level():
    while True:
        try:
            level = int(input("Level: "))
            if level in [1, 2, 3]:
                break
        except:
            pass
    return level


def generate_integer(digits):
    if digits == 1:
        min_num = 0
    else:
        min_num = 10 ** (digits - 1)
    max_num = (10 ** digits) -1
    rand_num = random.randint(min_num, max_num)
    return rand_num

main()
```

I have tried many alterations to my code. Still not being able to get it past the check50.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour]. SO is a Q&A site, but there's no question here and it's not clear what exactly you need help with. Maybe you need to learn [How to debug small programs](//ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)? Or if you want to ask about the platform, maybe [cs50.se] Stack Exchange would be a better place to ask? On the other hand, if you really do want to ask a question here, see [ask].

Comment: Part of the problem lies in how you are handing non-integer inputs by the user. If the user enters something like "FIVE", you are exiting the loop that takes guesses, printing 'EEE', failing to give them more attempts, and then generating a new problem without decrementing the number of questions remaining.  You may want to look up the `finally` clause of `try/except/else/finally`

Answer (score 2):

This program does not conform with the "structure your program as follows" directive of the spec

```
import random


def main():
    ...


def get_level():
    ...


def generate_integer(level):
    ...


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

It may be subtle, but it is significant to check50.